# Python default arguments as function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

There is two option for how to write python code. Which is better and why? The main question is can we use function as default argument in the OOP

```
def nonono(self, literature_title: str = None):
 """
 :param literature_title: the title of the new literature
 :return: requests.Response
 """
 data = {
     "title": get_random_string(),
 }
 if literature_title:
     data["title"] = literature_title
 return data
```

or

```
def nono(self, literature_title: str = get_random_string()):
 """
 :param literature_title: the title of the new literature
 :return: requests.Response
 """
 data = {
     "title": literature_title,
 }
 return data
```

Thanks

Comment: Post code as formatted text in your question not links to images of code

Comment: The default argument is only evaluated once, when the function is defined. So you'll always get the same random string.

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Barmar that code is not my code, just curious, and as I understand it is ok about the same random string.

Comment: Then the two versions work differently because `nonono` produces a different random string each time.

Comment: How did you mistype my screen name? Don't you know about the auto-completion after `@`?

Comment: Lol, I don't know how I'm mistyped

Comment: To bring more interest in you questions: 1/Give then a title that summarize the question. 2/ Describe what code is mean to do.